# Why is hibernate usage declining? Where to?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I thought that hibernate is the most used Java ORM, by far. Is its usage declining? If so, where are people migrating to?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are looking at search trends, not usage trends
2. A lot of people know Hibernate sufficiently for their daily needs, so they don't search as much for it. I expect this to be the dominant effect. Compare it for example with log4j which declines as well but certainly is still heavily used (and no the decline can't be explained with slf4j) http://www.google.com/trends?q=log4j%2C+slf4j
3. As mentioned above a lot of people are talking (searching) JPA although they might use Hibernate as the implementation.
4. Some people realized that maybe the whole ORM thing is a bad idea ... but that probably doesn't show significantly in the search trends

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be it's [JPA](http://www.google.com/trends?q=jpa) (of which Hibernate is also a provider). Because of this alias (which wasn't available in 2005) the declining trend for Hibernate may be misleading: some of the growing JPA uses are backed by the "declining" Hibernate, offsetting or even reversing the decline.

Comment: Sure, but JPA is just a standard. Actually Hibernate is (also) an implementation of JPA. The question is then which ORM which implements hibernate is most used?

Comment: @Matteo: Note that the graph is from Google Trends and this reflects what people *search for*, not what they *use*. It seems pretty logical that nowadays people more often search for things like "JPA many to many" even though they are in fact using Hibernate.

Comment: @Matteo It's still Hibernate that is the most widespread JPA implementation. Most probably followed by Eclipse TopLink.

Comment: @Matteo you mean "ORM which implements JPA", not "ORM which implements hibernate", right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes. But I think that Michael and gizmo have a good point. People do not only search to download but also for implementation problem and in this case they search for a JPA solution and not an Hibernate specific one (even if they use hibernate)